# multiple instance of jQuery slicebox on a single page

Tags: jquery, image, animation, slider, multiple-instances

I want to run multiple instances of jQuery slicebox on a single page. I have two instances set up however both are taking on the options from the second instance. The second " $.Slicebox.defaults " appears to be overriding the first " $.Slicebox.defaults ". I would like to make each instance independent. Does anybody know how to programmatically achieve this? This is my html and jQuery. As you can see I have attempted to change the id of both groups. The first I set to #sb-slider and second to #sb-slider2. This however does not isolate each instance. I would appreciate some proper guidance.

```
enter code here


        <section id="banners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="banner_box">
                    <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">                    
                        <li><a href=""><img src="images/image_1.jpg"  target="_blank"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><img src="images/image_2.jpg"  target="_blank"/></a></li>                                            
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="banner_box2">
                    <ul id="sb-slider2" class="sb-slider">
                        <li><a href=""><img src="images/image_3.jpg"  target="_blank"/></a></li>                     
                        <li><a href=""><img src="images/image_4.jpg"  target="_blank"/></a></li>                                                                    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>  





<script>
    $(function() {
        var Page = (function() {
            var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( '#nav-dots' ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( 'span' ),
                $shadow = $( '#shadow' ).hide(),
                slicebox = $( '#sb-slider' ).slicebox( {
                    onReady : function() {
                        $navArrows.show();
                        $navDots.show();
                        $shadow.show();
                    },
                    onBeforeChange : function( pos ) {
                    $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                    $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                    }
                }),
                init = function() {
                    initEvents();
                },
                initEvents = function() {
                    // add navigation events
                    $navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click', function() {
                        slicebox.next();
                        return false;
                    });
                    $navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click', function() {
                        slicebox.previous();
                        return false;
                    });
                    $nav.each( function( i ) {
                        $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
                            var $dot = $( this );
                            if( !slicebox.isActive()) {
                                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                            }
                            slicebox.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                };
                return { init : init };
        })();
        Page.init();
    });

    $('#sb-slider').slicebox();
    $.Slicebox.defaults = {
        // (v)ertical, (h)orizontal or (r)andom
        orientation : 'r',
        // perspective value
        perspective : 1200,
        // number of slices / cuboids
        // needs to be an odd number 15 => number > 0 (if you want the limit higher, 
        // change the _validate function).
        cuboidsCount : 5,
        // if true then the number of slices / cuboids is going to be random (cuboidsCount is overwitten)
        cuboidsRandom : true,
        // the range of possible number of cuboids if cuboidsRandom is true
        // it is strongly recommended that you do not set a very large number 
        maxCuboidsCount : 5,
        // each cuboid will move x pixels left / top (depending on orientation). 
        // The middle cuboid doesn't move. the middle cuboid's neighbors will 
        // move disperseFactor pixels
        disperseFactor : 10,
        // color of the hidden sides
        colorHiddenSides : '#222222',
        // the animation will start from left to right. The left most 
        // cuboid will be the first one to rotate
        // this is the interval between each rotation in ms
        sequentialFactor : 150,
        // animation speed
        // this is the speed that takes "1" cuboid to rotate
        speed : 600,
        // transition easing
        easing : 'ease',
        // if true the slicebox will start the animation automatically
        autoplay : true,
        // time (ms) between each rotation, if autoplay is true
        interval: 500,
        // the fallback will just fade out / fade in the items
        // this is the time fr the fade effect
        fallbackFadeSpeed : 300,    
        // callbacks
        onBeforeChange : function( position ) { return false; },
        onAfterChange : function( position ) { return false; }
    };
</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var Page = (function() {
            var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( '#nav-dots' ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( 'span' ),
                $shadow = $( '#shadow' ).hide(),
                slicebox2 = $( '#sb-slider2' ).slicebox( {
                    onReady : function() {
                        $navArrows.show();
                        $navDots.show();
                        $shadow.show();
                    },
                    onBeforeChange : function( pos ) {
                    $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                    $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                    }
                }),
                init = function() {
                    initEvents();
                },
                initEvents = function() {
                    // add navigation events
                    $navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click', function() {
                        slicebox.next();
                        return false;
                    });
                    $navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click', function() {
                        slicebox.previous();
                        return false;
                    });
                    $nav.each( function( i ) {
                        $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
                            var $dot = $( this );
                            if( !slicebox.isActive()) {
                                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                            }
                            slicebox.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                };
                return { init : init };
        })();
        Page.init();
    });

    $('#sb-slider2').slicebox();
    $.Slicebox.defaults = {
        // (v)ertical, (h)orizontal or (r)andom
        orientation : 'r',
        // perspective value
        perspective : 1200,
        // number of slices / cuboids
        // needs to be an odd number 15 => number > 0 (if you want the limit higher, 
        // change the _validate function).
        cuboidsCount : 5,
        // if true then the number of slices / cuboids is going to be random (cuboidsCount is overwitten)
        cuboidsRandom : true,
        // the range of possible number of cuboids if cuboidsRandom is true
        // it is strongly recommended that you do not set a very large number 
        maxCuboidsCount : 4,
        // each cuboid will move x pixels left / top (depending on orientation). 
        // The middle cuboid doesn't move. the middle cuboid's neighbors will 
        // move disperseFactor pixels
        disperseFactor : 10,
        // color of the hidden sides
        colorHiddenSides : '#222222',
        // the animation will start from left to right. The left most 
        // cuboid will be the first one to rotate
        // this is the interval between each rotation in ms
        sequentialFactor : 150,
        // animation speed
        // this is the speed that takes "1" cuboid to rotate
        speed : 600,
        // transition easing
        easing : 'ease',
        // if true the slicebox will start the animation automatically
        autoplay : true,
        // time (ms) between each rotation, if autoplay is true
        interval: 10000,
        // the fallback will just fade out / fade in the items
        // this is the time fr the fade effect
        fallbackFadeSpeed : 300,    
        // callbacks
        onBeforeChange : function( position ) { return false; },
        onAfterChange : function( position ) { return false; }
    };
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's only one `$.Slicebox.defaults` - that's why it's the "defaults".  It like having a browser with 2 tabs open - you can change the settings for each tab, but if you change the settings for the browser then it affects both tabs.  .defaults = the browser in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how to correct the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slicebox documentation is a bit thin on the ground, but it follows a standard approach for a jquery plugin:

```
$.Slicebox = function( options, element ) {
```

Rather than call `.defaults`, you pass the options to the slicebox initialiser, eg:

```
$('#sb-slider').slicebox({
    orientation : 'v'
});
$('#sb-slider2').slicebox({
    orientation : 'h'
});
```

Make sure you set any defaults *before* you call `.slicebox(options)`